# pyautogui doubleClick not working on OSX

Tags: python, macos, pyautogui

This is my first question so apologies in advanced for everything I'll do wrong in the next lines.

I am having issues with the doubleClick function from pyautogui on mac with OSX.
Lately I have written some python code using the following libraries

```
from time import sleep
from random import uniform as r
from pyautogui import click, doubleClick, press, moveTo, mouseDown, mouseUp
from webbrowser import open_new_tab
```

Even by trying the simplest combination

```
x1, y1 = (300, 375)
doubleClick(x=x1, y=y1)
```

there is no action taking place. I have tried two quick clicks with an interval, both also got no results from that.

I am experiencing this as a major issues and have checked now on several mac machines (5+) and the issue is always there and I cannot find any reference in other questions or on the internet.

Is anyone else experiencing the same?

Thank you already for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Found a [fix here](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/pull/72). (Just make sure you first activated the window you need to double click in, with a single click. I forgot and now it works perfectly.)

Comment: That's great! Thank you so much, all is working properly now!